# Proving this Hall algebra is commutative without Matlis duality

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters, p-groups

For a finite abelian $p$-group $G$ we have that 
$$
  G \simeq \mathbf{Z}/(p)^{\lambda_1} \oplus \dotsb \oplus  \mathbf{Z}/(p)^{\lambda_r}
$$
for some positive integers $\lambda_1 \geq \dotsb \geq \lambda_r$. Note that $G$ is uniquely determined by $p$ and this partition $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_r)$, so let's call $\lambda$ the *type* of $G$. For types $\lambda$, $\mu$, and $\nu$, define the *Hall number* $g_{\mu,\nu}^\lambda(p)$ to be the number of normal subgroups $N \mathrel{\triangleleft} G$ of type $\nu$ such that $G/N$ has type $\mu$. These Hall numbers serve as the structure constants of an associative algebra called the [Hall algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_algebra).

It turns out that this algebra is commutative, i.e. $g_{\mu,\nu}^\lambda(p) = g_{\nu,\mu}^\lambda(p)$. The proof of this that I'm looking at, following the more general theory in MacDonald's *Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials*, goes like this: You realize that we're looking at the category of finite-length modules over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, the [$p$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number). The [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbf{Z}(p^\infty)$ is the [injective hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_hull) of $\boldsymbol{k} = \mathbf{Z}/(p)$ in this category, and the functor $\mathrm{Hom}({-},\mathbf{Z}(p^\infty))$, via [Matlis duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matlis_duality), gives you a bijection of the short exact sequences in question, so $g_{\mu,\nu}^\lambda(p) = g_{\nu,\mu}^\lambda(p)$.

Proving this can also be approached by developing the theory of [characters of finite abelian groups](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf), [section 3](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf#page=6) in particular. But this is really the same approach in a different language: $\mathbf{Z}(p^\infty)$ plays the role of $S_1$ in this context. But in either approach, we're introducing some heavy stuff just to prove a fact about $p$-groups and partitions. Is there a elementary way to prove that $g_{\mu,\nu}^\lambda(p) = g_{\nu,\mu}^\lambda(p)$ in the case of finite abelian $p$-groups?

Comment: You can replace $\mathbf{Z}\left(p^\infty\right)$ in the duality argument by its "finite approximation" $\mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z}$, where $p^N$ is an upper bound on the sizes of your $p$-groups. This makes everything more elementary (it is certainly a lot easier to prove that each group $\mathbf{Z}/p^k\mathbf{Z}$ is isomorphic to its "$N$-dual" group $\operatorname{Hom}\left(\mathbf{Z}/p^k\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z}\right)$ when $k \leq N$).

Comment: Then we don't have to bring up the Prüfer group at all. :) But then we have to do some manual labor to show the map $\mathrm{Hom}(G, \mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z}) \to \mathrm{Hom}(N, \mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z})$ is a surjective. And we've still gotta define $\mathbf{Z}_p$ because these are all $\mathbf{Z}_p$ modules. ... or do you?

Comment: You don't need to define $\mathbf{Z}_p$; you can read "finite abelian $p$-group" for "$\mathbf{Z}_p$-module" (since all of your $\mathbf{Z}_p$-modules are finite).

Comment: Do you mean $G \cong \mathbf{Z}/(p)^{\lambda_1} \oplus \dotsb \oplus  \mathbf{Z}/(p^r)^{\lambda_r}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: No, he doesn't.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Well, does he mean $ G \cong \mathbf{Z}/(p^{\lambda_1}) \oplus \dotsb \oplus  \mathbf{Z}/(p^{\lambda_r})$?

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent to what he is writing. (We always have $\left(n\right)^k = \left(n^k\right)$ as ideals.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Oh yeah! I got stuck in $\mathbf{Z}_p$-Mod. But those are just group $\mathrm{Hom}$s and $\mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z}$ are still "injective over" $N$ and $G$ as groups. Okay. So now the only tough part is showing that $G \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(G, \mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z})$ since they have the same type. And maybe motivate the use of $\mathrm{Hom}({-},\mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z})$? That's not bad though. When I posted this question, I was hoping someone would have an idea that didn't use $\mathrm{Hom}({-},\mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: The (non-canonical) isomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Hom}\left(G, \mathbb{Z}/p^N\mathbb{Z}\right)$ is easy to see (it suffices to show it when $G = \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k \leq N$; but then it is straightforward). It may indeed be a bit harder to show that $\operatorname{Hom}\left(-, \mathbb{Z}/p^N\mathbb{Z}\right)$ is an exact (not just left-exact) functor. (I don't know right off my hat how this is proven.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg The functor $\mathrm{Hom}({-},\mathbf{Z}(p^\infty))$ is immediately left-exact because $\mathbf{Z}(p^\infty)$ is injective (divisible), so I imagine that proving $\mathrm{Hom}({-},\mathbf{Z}/(p^N\mathbf{Z}))$ is left-exact would require one to unpeel the proof that "divisible implies injective" and say something about $\mathbf{Z}/p^N\mathbf{Z}$ being "sufficiently divisible" relative to $N$ and $G$.

Comment: This is pretty old, I realize, but *yet another* way of thinking about the duality functor in the case of finite abelian $p$-groups is simply $D=\mathrm{Hom}(\bullet,\mathbf{C}^\times)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commutativity of the Hall algebra is saying that you can 'turn short exact sequences around', so is essentially equivalent to having a duality. You don't necessarily need the Prüfer group, though. You can take the 'usual' injective $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ for abelian groups. Then $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)\cong\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ is clear, sending a homomorphism $f$ to the image of the cyclic generator $f(1)$.

In the 'algebraic' setting, rather than the 'number theoretic' setting, the same result holds. Here you are taking finite dimensional $k[t]$-modules on which $t$ acts nilpotently; equivalently finite dimensional $k[[t]]$ modules. In this case one can instead use the usual vector space duality $D=\mathrm{Hom}_k(-,k)$. When the field $k$ is finite, the corresponding Hall algebra is symmetric.